# Как дополнить число лидирующими произвольными цифрами?

Tags: sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить цифры к числовому значению?

Например:

```
было    как нужно
0001    990001
9999    999999
```

Тип числовой.

Comment: Update MyTable SET Column1 =  Column1  + 990000

Answer (score 0):

Прибавить 990000 или сколько нужно.

Comment: Ватсон, этот человек -- програмист: даёт совершенно точные, но бесполезные ответы (С) из какого-то анекдота ))))) "Выглядит нормально" -- из очереди проверок.

Comment: @AK Ну почему же бесполезные?  Нужный результат же достигнется :)